# Book about a boy who learns magic and becomes the hero

Tags: story-identification, books

In this book a young boy witnesses magic as part of an act in his town square by a traveling merchant (designed to locate kids that are sensitive to magic) in a tall brightly colored caravan. That evening the merchant attempts to kidnap him, or he does, can't remember. I believe his father dies during this altercation. Anyway the kid ends up learning magic from a couple different places, and gets his revenge.

I do not remember the cover art as I listened to the book through Audible. I listened to it about a year ago. I do not remember the particulars about how the magic worked, only that the boy reacted to a conjured orb of light cast by the traveling caravan merchant, who was there to abduct the magic sensitive children.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Do you recall the cover art?  How did magic work, and what kind of magic did the hero perform?

Comment: I do not remember the cover art as I listened to the book through audible. I listened to it about a year ago. I do not remember the particulars about how the magic worked.. only that the boy reacted to a conjured orb of light cast by the traveling caravan merchant, who was there to abduct the magic sensitive children.

Comment: Do you read/listen to Isekai or Litrpg? Because this sounds similar to a couple I have read.

Comment: I do not, this was more of a young adult novel,probably around 20 hours of narration.